# how to gather object information when using onListItemClick to start a new activity

Tags: android, sqlite, android-activity

**I've this eventhandler:**

```
@Override
        protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
         // TODO Auto-generated method stub
         //super.onListItemClick(l, v, position, id);
         String selection = l.getItemAtPosition(position).toString();

         Intent myIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, sondaggioActivity.class);
         MainActivity.this.startActivity(myIntent);
         //Toast.makeText(this, selection, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
```

the item clicked is the listview rappresentation of:

```
public class categorie {
      private long id;
      private String nome;
      private long preferita;

      public long getId() {
        return id;
      }

      public void setId(long id) {
        this.id = id;
      }

      public String getNome() {
        return nome;
      }

      public void setNome(String nome) {
        this.nome = nome;
      }



      public long getPreferita() {
        return preferita;
    }

    public void setPreferita(long preferita) {
        this.preferita = preferita;
    }

    // Will be used by the ArrayAdapter in the ListView
      @Override
      public String toString() {
        return nome;
      }
    }
```

and I list them by:

```
datasource = new pollDataSource(this);
        datasource.open();

        Cursor values = datasource.getAllCategorie();

        String[] categorieColumns =
            {
                MySQLiteHelper.COLUMN_NOME   // Contract class constant containing the word column name

            };


            int[] mWordListItems = { R.id.categoria_label };


        SimpleCursorAdapter adapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(
                getApplicationContext(),               // The application's Context object
                R.layout.single_list_item,             // A layout in XML for one row in the ListView
                values,                                // The result from the query
                categorieColumns,                      // A string array of column names in the cursor
                mWordListItems,                        // An integer array of view IDs in the row layout
                0);                                    // Flags (usually none are needed)


        setListAdapter(adapter);
```

In the new activity, i would like to gather some "questions" in the database in a given category (the one i have clicked)... how do I could pass the clicked category to the new activity?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably want this:

```
Cursor data = (Cursor)l.getItemAtPosition(position);
String cat = data.getString(cursor.getIndexColumn(MySQLiteHelper.COLUMN_NOME));
Intent myIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, sondaggioActivity.class);
myIntent.putExtra("categorieName", cat);
MainActivity.this.startActivity(myIntent);
```

Then in the `sondaggioActivity` activity you could use `getIntent()` to get the `Intent` that started the activity and retrieve the categorie name.

Comment: is the cursor = Cursor? or cursor is something else?

Answer (score 1):

do you know about intents? you're allowed to put simple primitives, strings and lots more into the intent that will start the next activity. It functions with key-value relationships like a `HashMap`. here's a simple example.

```
@Override
protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
    int selection = position;
    Intent myIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, sondaggioActivity.class);
    myIntent.putExtra("SELECTION", selection); // <--- put the value (KEY, VALUE)
    MainActivity.this.startActivity(myIntent);
}
```

Then in your new activity:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    int category = getIntent().getExtras().getInt("SELECTION"); // <-- get the value, with the same  KEY
    switch (category) {
    case 1:
        // do something
        break;
    case 2:
        // do something else
        break;
    }
}
```